# Mono gets OnCancel instead of OnSuccessOrError after successful request

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I have a SpringBoot Webflux app which implements a `WebFilter` to log success/error once a `Publisher` completes.
My `Webfilter` is similar to the following:

```
public class MyFilter implements WebFilter {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyFilter.class);

@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    return chain.filter(exchange)
            .doOnCancel(() -> {
                LOG.info("Cancelled");
            })
            .doOnSuccess(aVoid -> {
                LOG.info("Success");
            })
            .doOnSuccessOrError((aVoid, throwable) -> {
                if (throwable == null) {
                    LOG.info("Completed successfully");
                } else {
                    LOG.error("An error occurred", throwable);
                }
            });
}
```

Since SpringBoot 2.1.5, the `WebFilter` does not work as expected anymore. Instead of getting the `doOnSuccessOrError` event I now get `doOnCancel`. This only happens when using Netty since version 0.8.7. When using Undertow, it works as expected.

In all cases the Web requests completes successfully, returning the correct data to the client.

Please see DEBUG/TRACE logs below:

```
[reactor-http-nio-3] DEBUG o.s.h.codec.json.Jackson2JsonEncoder - [6bfed744] Encoding [{"errors":[]}]
[reactor-http-nio-3] DEBUG r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations - [id: 0x6bfed744, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8071 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:55927] Decreasing pending responses, now 0
[reactor-http-nio-3] DEBUG r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations - [id: 0x6bfed744, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8071 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:55927] Last HTTP packet was sent, terminating the channel
[reactor-http-nio-3] TRACE r.netty.channel.ChannelOperations - [id: 0x6bfed744, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8071 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:55927] Disposing ChannelOperation from a channel
java.lang.Exception: ChannelOperation terminal stack
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:391)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.cleanHandlerTerminate(HttpServerOperations.java:519)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.operationComplete(HttpTrafficHandler.java:314)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.operationComplete(HttpTrafficHandler.java:54)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:502)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:476)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:415)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:540)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:529)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:101)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.trySuccess(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:48)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.safeSuccess(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:715)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:270)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.removeBytes(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:350)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:411)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:939)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:906)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1370)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:727)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:533)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:358)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:727)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:127)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:764)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:789)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:757)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:812)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1036)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:305)
     ...
[reactor-http-nio-3] INFO  c.m.d.MyFilter - Cancelled
[reactor-http-nio-3] DEBUG r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler - [id: 0x6bfed744, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8071 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:55927] No ChannelOperation attached. Dropping: EmptyLastHttpContent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in Spring Framework (see [spring-framework#22952](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22952)) and especially Reactor Netty ([reactor-netty#741](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/741)). There is no known workaround for that right now.